# UWP Listview around Grid

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

I need a custom layout like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUR6i.png) in XAML with a listview around an element.
I tried WrapPanel, VariableSizedWrapGrid and RelativePane, but nothing matches.

If you have any idea .. Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to convince a designer to make normal design than to create such a miracle. However, if you like pointless but challenging work, you can try to make custom ItemsPanel for the GridView.

Comment: I have to say it is difficult to implement such a custom ItemsPanel for GridView. If you don't use data binding, you could use Grid to implement this layout instead of GridView, and you only need to set the position of the special element to `Grid.RowSpan="2"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.
Finaly a RelativePanel with codebehind do the trick.